# Ubuntu does not boot - Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: dual-boot, mac, refind

I want to boot Ubuntu 16.04 in an environment of Mac OX El Capitan.

I followed [Rod's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688632/dual-boot-mac-el-captain-along-with-ubuntu-14-04/766919#766919) in [Dual Boot Mac El Captain along with Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688632/dual-boot-mac-el-captain-along-with-ubuntu-14-04) , but I am still having a problem.

I disabled the SIP before installing refind. The disk is partitioned and formatted with FAT to install Ubuntu and I created a [Ubuntu USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick). rFInd loads before booting but the system (Ubuntu) does not load. I cannot give or test any sequence to install Ubuntu, only a black screen! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This question is partly a reply to an answer to a different question. Please edit it so it can stand on its own.

Comment: When you boot your computer with the Ubuntu USB stick in a USB port,  could you please describe what boot options are showing in reFind?

Comment: Have you considered installing Ubuntu in EFI mode without using rEFInd. I think rEFInd is a nice boot manager (I have it installed on my Mac), but it is not required to boot Ubuntu on a Mac.