# Change startup disk from OS X to Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, startup, mac, macbook-pro

I am a novice and I am on a Mac. Help me anyway.

I need to change the start up disk to be my Ubuntu 16.04 partition instead of my OS X partition.

A Mac guy added users to my OS X to replace the battery and promptly I cannot start up nor see my Linux partition.

I know this is due to Mac changing the start up disk to itself.

I cannot change the start up disk back in OS X's settings.

Is there something I can do in Ubuntu to fix it?

- 2009 Macbook Pro
- OS X El Capitan
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Currently booting from Ubuntu 16.04 LiveUSB

Answer (score 0):

There's not anything you can do from within Ubuntu because your issue has to do with your **bootloader**, which is the software that runs before any operating system is loaded.

Generally, you can make changes in BIOS settings (your motherboard firmware) to allow you to select a device to boot, or to give the option to adjust boot priority.

Apple's bootloader options will appear if you hold the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (option) key when booting; however your Linux install will not be present since it is not a supported or recognized OS in Apple's proprietary firmware.

If you want to dual boot Ubuntu with Apple hardware, you will need to replace Apple's bootloader with something like [rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688632/dual-boot-mac-el-captain-along-with-ubuntu-14-04/688692#688692).  Due to Apple's closed-source approach to their hardware and software, it is unfortunately not very novice-friendly and it may also void your warranty / support.

Comment: Luckily, I don't have a warranty!

I figured out a way to install Ubuntu and run it, but an apple tech messed it up for me by adding users in OS X

Do you know anywhere I can get help with the apple command line?